# Does completing the Desmond memories have any effect on the Ezio campaign?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

AKA, Is there anything to be gained by indulging my whiny, emo, future self?

Ugh.  Desmond.  I can't stand this guy.  I've unlocked a few of the Desmond missions, but I've been putting them off.  In previous games, the Desmond parts of the game were by far my least favorite parts of the game.

I've considered maybe going and doing one or two of these missions just so I can get them out of the way, and so that I'm not left with just a load of Desmond missions when I finish the game proper.

However, it occurs to me that perhaps there are benefits in the Ezio timeline if I finish the Desmond missions now.  Should I prioritize the Desmond missions?  Will I go crazy if I do them all at once?  Or can I safely ignore them till the game is over?

Comment: From Eurogamer.net's review: 'Here is what I regard as an ideal level of Desmond: I want him to show up at the opening of the game and say, "Hello, folks, I'm Desmond Miles. I'm about to step into my magical history machine and pretend to be a fabulously fun and likeable Italian fellow from the Renaissance era. Won't you join me on this thrilling adventure?" Cue title screen, and Desmond goes away. I would also allow him to appear in the credits giving the thumbs-up sign with a word balloon that says, "Thanks for playing!"'

Comment: To be fair, by the end of *Revelations* Desmond is significantly less whiny, and I did find his backstory at least somewhat interesting.  (I also thought the levels were fun but they're SIGNIFICANTLY different from the standard gameplay so YMMV.)  There are only five of them anyway - honestly, I think I spent longer playing as Desmond than I did as Altair!

Comment: @Shinrai, Yeaaaahhhhh, I'm going to play his stages too, eventually.  I'll be making this face the whole time though: **:|**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can safely ignore them. What they give you doesn't affect the outcome of the game. They're only for storyline and achievements.

Comment: _And_ some multiplayer emblems but they're rather lame.

Comment: Oh, and you unlock the Desmond skin for Ezio! >.>

Comment: @Shinrai, So instead of looking like a Renaissance badass in full combat armor bristling with pointy bits of metal, I could wander around in jeans and a hoodie?  This is a *reward*?

Comment: @agent86 - I never said it was a reward :3

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm.

> You can play the full Ezio campaign without even doing one of
>   Desmond's memories.

Source: Desmond's memories crashed every time I stepped into the glowing "load" portal. Thus not allowing me to do any. Completed the game without any issues.